# Ocelot, Identity, IdentityServer4 and API Resource, how to grant access on a role basis

Tags: .net-core, microservices, identityserver4, ocelot

I am trying to learn how a microservices approach with net core should be. So after a lot of tutorials this is what I have got so far:

1. I have created two apis projects: Company and Package. Ports 5002 and 5010
2. I need a gateway, Ocelot is the one. I have this configuration:

```
{

  "Routes": [
    // Company Api
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/company/{everything}",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 5002
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/company/{everything}",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [
        "GET"
      ],
      "AuthenticationOptions": {
        "AuthenticationProviderKey": "TestKey",
        "AllowedScopes": []
      },
      "AddHeadersToRequest": {
        "CustomerId": "Claims[sub] > value"
      }
    },
    // Anonymous Company Api
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/company/getHomeSections",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 5002
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/anonymous/company/getHomeSections",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [
        "GET"
      ]
    },
    // Package Api
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/package/{everything}",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 5010
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/package/{everything}",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [
        "GET"
      ],
      "AuthenticationOptions": {
        "AuthenticationProviderKey": "TestKey",
        "AllowedScopes": []
      }
    }
  ],
  "GlobalConfiguration": {
    "BaseUrl": "http://localhost:5000"
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

3. I have a identityServer4 configured with identity and mongoDB. Works like a charm.

I have configured a client in angular 10. I can log in, I get the token and everything works as expected.

Now my big question is, how do I grant access to users on a API / Role basis? So lets say Role A has access to company/read and Role B to company/read and company/write?

How do actually achieve that?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how do I grant access to users on a API / Role basis?

There are two ways:

***On the client***

This method doesn't involve the gateway at all, just IdentityServer.

If you just want role-based behaviour in the UX - to allow/disallow certain calls or to hide/show certain screens/components, you can do the following:

1. Model your roles as user claims in Identity Server
2. Have the UX interrogate the bearer JWT returned at login and unpack the claims collection
3. Apply your role-based UX logic based on the discovered role(s).

***In the gateway/on the back-end***

This is more complicated, but if you want to have role-based behaviour in your back-end then you will need to code for it in your services. One way of doing this is to have each service accept a collection of roles as a header parameter, for example. Then you can:

1. Model your roles as user claims in Identity Server
2. In Ocelot expose the upstream service path without any roles header parameter
3. When the UX makes a request, have Ocelot inject the "roles" claims as a downstream http header (in the same way you are currently doing with the customerId)
4. Then you can have each service make a decision about whether to allow the request based on the roles

However, this feels clumsy. Thinking about access control at the service-level, roles feel a bit too coarse-grained.

***Maybe a third way...***

So, role-based behaviour works well on your front-end, but what about your back-end?

Since you are already taking advantage of the ability to inject the CustomerId user claim into the downstream service, we should consider another solution.

Rather than role based behaviour on your back-end, why not just use the *resource identifier* to control access? For example, a private http operation to do with a customer can be defined with the customerId as part of the path:

```
GET /customers/{customerId}
```

In Ocelot, the upstream path can be exposed as

```
GET /customers
```

The customerId claim is injected into the downstream path when the request is received on the gateway (note: Ocelot does not support path parameter injection out-of-the-box. You need to create a class derived from [DelegatingHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.delegatinghandler?view=netcore-3.1), and use it with the `DelegatingHandlers[]` collection in the ocelot.json to do [this](https://ocelot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features/delegatinghandlers.html)).

In a similar vein, you can secure your company API by creating an Ocelot route from `GET /company` to `GET /company/{companyId}` where companyId is a user claim.

Combined with role-based behaviour on your front-end, this approach gives you much finer-grained access control on your gateway/back-end than you can get with role-based behaviour. You get the best of both worlds.

Comment: This is a very complete and nice response! I am still old fashioned and I kept living in the role based ages. I will take a look at your thrid option, I feel it is more appropriate!  Thanks!

Comment: No worries. I think that role-based access works well if services are more RPC style. For resource-style services it's better to think in terms of public/private operations. This is why I don't usually use the /{everything} path in Ocelot for private operations.